# Compose ConstraintLayout margin not working

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

[image]
There seems to be no margin whatsoever even though I explicitly set the margin between the image and title to be 12dp

What am I missing?

Setting the heights to `Dimension.value(0dp)` did not do the trick btw

My view component:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun GenericEmptyState() {
    MaterialTheme() {
        ConstraintLayout(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(1f)
                .background(Color.White)
                .padding(24.dp)
        ) {
            val (image, title, text, cta) = createRefs()

            Image(
                painterResource(R.drawable.hearts),
                contentDescription = "hearts",
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(image) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    height = Dimension.value(150.dp)
                    width = Dimension.value(150.dp)
                }
            )

            Text(
                "this is the title",
                Modifier.constrainAs(title) {
                    top.linkTo(image.bottom, 12.dp)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    height = Dimension.wrapContent
                })

            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat",
                Modifier.constrainAs(text) {
                    top.linkTo(title.bottom, 12.dp)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }
            )

            createVerticalChain(image, title, text, chainStyle = ChainStyle.Packed(0.5f))
        }
    }
}
```

Compose version 1.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `createVerticalChain` as intended. I haven't found this function description in Compose documentation - seems it's still under development, but `androidx.constraintlayout.widget` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#createVerticalChain(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20int)) (on which Compose ConstraintLayout should be based) contains the following description:

> This operation sets all the related margins to 0.

Removing this line solves your problem.

---

Also Here's how you can build the same layout without `ConstraintLayout`:

1. Use `Column` to place items.
2. Space items by `12.dp` using arrangement
3. Center items using alignment

```
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(1f)
        .background(Color.White)
        .padding(24.dp)
) {
    Image(
        painterResource(R.drawable.my_image_2),
        contentDescription = "hearts",
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
    )

    Text("this is the title")

    Text(LoremIpsum(30).values.first())
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PhilipDukhov, will try it out ASAP. Do you know if such limitation is a design choice or it's a TODO item. I asked because ConstraintLayout Compose version is 1.0.0 now and my searches returned nothing on the matter

Comment: @ericn I've updated my answer with details

Comment: why would you want to do that? it's like the bad old days of web development.

Comment: well, you can also set `width` and/or `height` with `Dimension.fillToConstraints` and all margins would work

Comment: so what is the solution then? There are more complicated layouts which still should be implemented with ConstraintLayout, example from the question of course doesn't need any ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar case. If anyone do the following, can solve the problem

```
...
Text(
    "this is the title",
    Modifier
        // First, set padding above constrainAs
        .padding(top = 12.dp)
        .constrainAs(title) {
            // Remove margin value
            top.linkTo(image.bottom)
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            height = Dimension.wrapContent
        })

Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat",
    Modifier
        // set padding top too
        .padding(top = 12.dp)
        .constrainAs(text) {
            // Remove margin value
            top.linkTo(title.bottom)
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
        })
...
```

Since Modifier processes layout sequentially, so if padding is set first, the calculated size is used.

Comment: this is bad to use padding instead of margin if you want then link some other components parallel. so basically you make components bigger, it doesn't matter how you set paddings above or below